# Finding the middle element in a linked list using double pointer method

Tags: c

I wrote the following function which returns the middle element of a linked list, which uses the double pointer method

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start;

void middleelement()
{
struct node *x=start,*y=start;
int n=0;

if(start==NULL)
{
    printf("\nThere are no elments in the list");
}

else
{
    while((x->next)!=NULL)
    {
        x=x->next->next;
        y=y->next;
        n++;
    }

    printf("\nMiddle element is %d",y->data);
}
}
```

However, whenever I run the functions, the **Windows explorer stops working**
What is the flaw in the code?
Is there any better algorithm than this to find the middle element?

Comment: What if the list has an odd number of elements?

Comment: what if `x=x->next->next;` is equal to null?

Comment: If a simple/test application is able to stop a completely different process (Windows explorer) from working (for *any* reason, including bugs in the simple/test application), then the problem is the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of entries is odd, your `x` will end up being `NULL`, so when the next loop iteration dreferences it, your program is going to crash. You should modify your condition to account for that:

```
while(x && x->next) {
    ...
}
```

Comparing with `NULL` is optional in C, so you can skip the `!= NULL` to shorten the condition.

Of course passing the `start` parameter through a global variable is unorthodox, to say the least. It would be much better to pass it as a regular function parameter.

Comment: @CSSS That is the only modification that you need. Replace the loop condition, and run your code. Everything else seems to be fine.